# Creating an account with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Is it a good idea to use Javascript to create an account or is it prone to security risks? If it's fine, I need to be able to display some errors if the username or email address already exists.

e.g.

Javascript:

```
function createAccount() {
   var new_user = $('#new-username').val();
   var new_pass = $('#new-password').val();
   var confirm_pass = $('#confirm-password').val();
   var new_email = $('#new-email').val();
   $.post('createaccount.php', {
       new_user: new_user,
       new_pass: new_pass,
       confirm_pass: confirm_pass,
       new_email: new_email
   });
}
```

createaccount.php:

```
$new_username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['new_user']);
$new_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['new_pass']);
$new_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['new_email']);
$confirm_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['confirm_pass']);

$query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$new_username'");
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
$query2 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$new_email'");
$numrows2 = mysqli_num_rows($query2);

...

echo json_encode(array('numrows'=>$numrows,'numrows2'=>$numrows2));
```

I need to be able to use `numrows` and `numrows2` somehow with $.getJSON to alert some errors (like the username already exists, or the email address is already in use). Any way to do this?

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text**

Comment: @SLaks Where is the OP storing passwords in plain text?

Comment: @Ian: `mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['confirm_pass'])`

Comment: or at all for that matter

Comment: @SLaks Ahh I see what you're getting at. I didn't see any **storage** but I see you could assume it would be stored as plaintext the way it's written

Comment: @Ian: Escaping before hashing is also wrong (though less bad).  On a related note, there is never a reason to escape both fields.

Comment: why would you assume that? nothing in the code indicated it?

Comment: @Dagon: `mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['confirm_pass'])`

Comment: so? your jsut making a massive leap

Comment: @Dagon The fact that they're `mysqli_real_escape_string`ing it would make me think they're preparing to use it immediately in a query. What kind of query would they use except for an INSERT? At least, that's what SLaks made me realize

Comment: @SLaks Yeah, I don't see a reason to escape before hashing. Would that even work? I feel like it produce a different hash. And you're right, no need to escape the confirm field

Answer (score 2):

HTTP requests sent from Javascript code are no more or less secure than HTTP requests sent from HTML forms.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my main question was how to display errors if the username or email already exists

Comment: @frosty: Return your validation / result as JSON, then read that JSON in the JS.

Answer (score 1):

It's fine, but you should have security checks in your PHP just like you normally would so that even if users manipulate the Javascript nothing malicious can be done.

Answer (score 0):

The other two answers sum it up pretty well. As long as you strip the data on the server side. There is one more thing that I think should be mentioned. If you don't have a SSL or other encrypted method setup, it is a good idea to encrypt it in javascript before sending it over. By doing that, you ensure that any prying eyes don't get a copy of the data being sent over the internet. It may also help you avoid having the NSA get a copy of your data. Javascript has no native functions for encryption, so you will have to get a non native library. Just google "javascript encryption" and you should find what you are looking for. There are many options. Good luck. Hope that helps.

Comment: Encryption in Javascript served over HTTP is useless

Comment: Depends on how you look at it. People looking at the data as it's being sent to the server would otherwise be able to view it unless you encrypt it or send it over an SSL connection.